# WooCommerce REST API Ajax Authentication error

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

The reason was that I was logged in to WP.

Looking for a reason here: [WooCommerce REST API Authentication fails when logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806785/woocommerce-rest-api-authentication-fails-when-logged-in)

---

I am trying to connect to **Woocommerce REST API** using **Ajax** (to read product data)

The following URL ...

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/1744?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx
```

... gives me this error:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot view this resource.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I also tried the same using **CURL** like:

```
curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/1744 \
-u ck_xxx:cs_xxx
```

And got the same error.

What could be wrong here?

**The key is read only**.

I am quite sure the error means that everything is ok but there's an issue with authentication.

---

Entering exactly the same information into **Advanced REST Client** Chrome  extension gives me exactly what I am looking for. Why is it not working with CURL or Ajax?

Even just pasting the URL at http://onlinecurl.com/ gets me `200 OK`

**EDIT:** Got the **CURL** working like this:

```
curl -XGET 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/30552?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=xxx'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce REST API Authentication fails when logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806785/woocommerce-rest-api-authentication-fails-when-logged-in)