# WooCommerce REST API Authentication fails when logged in

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, rest, wordpress-rest-api

WooCommerce REST API Authentication is failing when I am logged into Wordpress in the same browser.

Log out - everything works

Log in  - and get this error:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot view this resource.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Same goes for Ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/30552?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx',
    success:function(d){window.d = d;}
});
```

and when trying to access the same URL directly in the browser.

What could be causing this situtation?

I can't think of any useful reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed for WooCommerce 2.7.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/b1b536b5d2aa19a2967466acc90a6547955b8595